# AssertEquals failing . List size is returning more than actual size

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-data-jpa

everyone. I'm new to Spring and unit testing and I'm trying to test my repository layer. My test is failing when using assertEquals when asserting the size of my products list. In the first test, it says actual is 3 when clearly it should be 2.Same goes for the second test, it's returning 2 when it should be 1 after deletion of product1.I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

```
import com.eshop.shoppingcart.model.Product;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;


@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class ProductRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
   ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    void getAllProducts(){
        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setId(1L);
        product1.setName("The Stranger");
        product1.setPrice(124.5);
        product1.setPictureUrl("https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1590930002l/49552._SY475_.jpg");

        Product product2 = new Product();
        product2.setId(2L);
        product2.setName("Meditations");
        product2.setPrice(164.5);
        product2.setPictureUrl("https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1590930002l/49552._SY475_.jpg");

        productRepository.save(product1);
        productRepository.save(product2);

        List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();

        assertNotNull(products);
        assertThat(products).isNotNull();
        assertThat(products.size()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertEquals(2, products.size());

    }

    @Test
    void deleteProduct(){
        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.setId(1L);
        product1.setName("The Stranger");
        product1.setPrice(124.5);
        product1.setPictureUrl("https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1590930002l/49552._SY475_.jpg");
        productRepository.save(product1);
        Long id = product1.getId();

        Product product2 = new Product();
        product2.setId(2L);
        product2.setName("Meditations");
        product2.setPrice(164.5);
        product2.setPictureUrl("https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1590930002l/49552._SY475_.jpg");
        productRepository.save(product2);

        productRepository.delete(product1);
        List<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
        Optional<Product> retrievedProduct =  productRepository.findById(id);

        assertThat(retrievedProduct.isEmpty());
        assertEquals(1, products.size());

    }
}
```

Comment: When you run the `getAllProducts` test alone, does it pass?

Comment: Hi! No. It fails in assertThat and assertEquals. It says expected is 2 but was 3.

Comment: I think your best bet is enabling `show-sql` (`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`) and trying to see what commands are being executed when the test is run.

Answer (score 2):

You may add some code to clean the repository data.

It seems that you already have a product when the test starts.